# KStream result undefined

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a producer that produces to a topic - "test-qa2". I am trying to create a KStream out of this topic and print out it's values

The issue is it's not printing anything. On debug, the result of the KStream is undefined.

```
 public void test(){
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> customerKStream= builder.stream("testqa2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        customerKStream.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("Customer from Topic: " + value)));
    }
```

[image]

If you have any idea please can you guide me?

Answer (score 0):

That line itself doesn't return anything, so yes, the result will be undefined... You would need to set a breakpoint inside of the lambda rather than evaluate the entire line, and then you'd be able to inspect `key` or `value`, assuming that the `foreach` was triggered.

> The issue is it's not printing anything

Are you starting with `auto.offset.reset=latest` and/or haven't produced anything to the topic?

Note: If you want to test code, I suggest using `TopologyTestDriver` in a unit test rather than just plain void methods